# Бот для в вк . Как сделать несколько условий в if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, условия

Я делаю расписание и мне требуется , чтобы бот отвечал и на "пн" и на "понедельник". Я пробовал `or` и через запятую ,но не работает.

```
if event.object.text.lower() == "пн"(что тут должно стоять?)"понедельник" :
    ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if event.object.text.lower() == "пн" or event.object.text.lower() == "понедельник" :
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if event.object.text.lower() in ['пн', 'понедельник']:
```